# Security risk of XEN Server Free with public ip?

Tags: virtualization, xen, xenserver, citrix, hypervisor

I am having a dedicated machine,from some hosting company and i have KVM access to it  i wish to virtualize it using XEN's bare metal hyperviosr,(XEN server Free).

Will it be possible to manage VM's remotely through ssh or ssl using Citrix XENCentre.

Also what are the risk associated with it.

Will XEN server comes with ssh and iptables insatlled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a XenServer installed that faces the internet, we just use very long passwords for the XenCenter root user and ssh access.

I'm not sure but I think IPtables runs on them just fine ( in the end it's just a modded CentOS).

If you can I seriously advice to get a small firewall/router so you can VPN into it rather than face it all the time to the internet.

Comment: thanx Lucas kauffman...!!!